# Is there a way to cache AdMob ads?

Tags: ios, admob, offline-caching

I have an iOS app with AdMob integrated. I show some banner ads as well as interstitials. However, if the device is not connected to the internet, no ads are shown.

**Is there a way to cache ads and show them even if the user is offline?**

Or.. This would cause problems due to the fact that the ads usually open some kind of webpage when clicked and also report revenue back to the servers?

*Just a side note:* Why do free apps have ad free versions, when you could just disconnect from the internet and still have no ads?

Any input is appreciated! :)

Comment: Well addressing the side note, about why users don't just put their devices in airplane mode to avoid ads... While a small number of users would find ads so annoying to the point where they'd do such a thing, the vast majority of users *can't be bothered*. It's just too much hassle to set airplane mode > go use app > re-connect to Internet. Also, the vast majority of users would want to continue receiving messages and calls while in your app, therefore making airplane mode impossible anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to cache ads and show them even if the user is offline?

The ad-network's sdks have a caching mechanism (not all but most). But whether or not they display ads when offline completely depends on their tracking algorithm and their choice.

> Or.. This would cause problems due to the fact that the ads usually
>   open some kind of webpage when clicked and also report revenue back to
>   the servers?

Yes, that is one obvious reason. Merely displaying ads when no action can be taken upon clicking it is useless and will burden the advertiser with unfruitful costs.

> Just a side note: Why do free apps have ad free versions, when you
>   could just disconnect from the internet and still have no ads?

Not everyone would like to keep network off just to get rid of ads on one app. they will miss important notifications from other apps. Also, the free and paid separate versions are for different set of people. There are people who would legitimately want to remove ads and do not mind paying a small cost for it. They do not want the hassle of toggling the network every time they want to use particular apps.

Answer (score 0):

Ad free version,you can commit two version to app store.If you want to show ad offline,it's impossible because ad vendor can't know if and how often the ad is active.